# MongoDB Crashing on specific documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with MongoDB on Windows Server 2016 and I have a collection which has around 900,000 documents.
when I want to get some specific documents MongoDB crashes and MongoDB Server stops.

Query:

> db.getCollection("Products").find({DKPId: 797027})

all the documents that make MongoDB crash are in between 797027 and 797300, so they are near each other. and I don't any problem with the rest of documents.

It's not happening only with find or findOne, I can't even remove these documents.

Here's MongoDB Full Log

```
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.904+0330 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.908+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3592 port=20159 dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data 64-bit host=AvanServer
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.909+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.909+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.909+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.909+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.909+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.910+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.910+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.910+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.911+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.911+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 20159 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data", journal: { enabled: true }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 6.0 } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log" } }
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.913+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2019-01-07T13:24:40.913+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=6144M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
    2019-01-07T13:24:41.536+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1546854881:535937][3592:140718238684896], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 878/11392
    2019-01-07T13:24:41.853+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1546854881:853338][3592:140718238684896], txn-recover: Recovering log 878 through 879
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.046+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1546854882:45699][3592:140718238684896], txn-recover: Recovering log 879 through 879
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.232+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1546854882:232528][3592:140718238684896], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.265+0330 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.885+0330 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'The specified counter could not be found.' for counter '\Memory\Cache Bytes'
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.885+0330 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/data/diagnostic.data'
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.897+0330 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 20159
    2019-01-07T13:24:42.898+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Service running
    2019-01-07T13:24:48.666+0330 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51429 #1 (1 connection now open)
    2019-01-07T13:24:48.668+0330 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:51429 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-csharp-driver", version: "2.7.0.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393", architecture: "x86_64", version: "10.0.14393" }, platform: ".NET Core 4.6.25921.01" }
    2019-01-07T13:24:48.721+0330 I ACCESS   [conn1] Successfully authenticated as principal avanMongodbAdmin on admin
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.521+0330 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51430 #2 (2 connections now open)
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.531+0330 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:51430 conn2: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.3-10-g865d2fb" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows Server 2012", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.564+0330 I ACCESS   [conn2] Successfully authenticated as principal avanMongodbAdmin on admin
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.567+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:567192][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_block_read_off, 282: collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt: read checksum error for 81920B block at offset 52837900288: calculated block checksum of 2968014962 doesn't match expected checksum of 4237726079 Raw: [1546854890:567192][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_block_read_off, 282: collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt: read checksum error for 81920B block at offset 52837900288: calculated block checksum of 2968014962 doesn't match expected checksum of 4237726079
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.568+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:568215][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 1 of 80): 00 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.569+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:569157][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 2 of 80): 8c d8 af 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.570+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:569157][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 3 of 80): 63 61 72 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.571+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:570695][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 4 of 80): 0d 0f 0c 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.572+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:570695][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 5 of 80): 38 00 7b 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.573+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:572994][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 6 of 80): 3e e4 31 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.574+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:572994][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 7 of 80): 00 65 0d 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.574+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:574691][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 8 of 80): 17 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.575+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:574691][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 9 of 80): 2e 01 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.575+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:575712][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 10 of 80): 93 12 0e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.576+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:576099][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 11 of 80): 80 8c 0e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.576+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:576099][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 12 of 80): 6e 6f 74 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.577+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:576099][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 13 of 80): cc 03 6d 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.577+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:576099][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 14 of 80): d9 84 20 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.578+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:578441][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 15 of 80): 6e 74 61 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.579+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:579123][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 16 of 80): 01 ee 62 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.580+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:579914][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 17 of 80): 02 0b 76 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.580+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:579914][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 18 of 80): 98 00 d6 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.581+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:580879][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 19 of 80): 81 0e da 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.581+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:580879][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 20 of 80): d6 4d 01 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.582+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:581851][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 21 of 80): b1 01 21 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.582+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:581851][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 22 of 80): 69 65 fe 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.583+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:582831][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 23 of 80): 05 1e 08 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.583+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:582831][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 24 of 80): d9 86 0e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.584+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:583811][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 25 of 80): eb ca bc 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.584+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 26 of 80): 6a 43 02 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.585+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 27 of 80): 07 01 01 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.586+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 28 of 80): 65 63 01 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.586+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 29 of 80): 72 00 63 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.587+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 30 of 80): 43 00 6f 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.588+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 31 of 80): 00 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.589+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 32 of 80): c8 ff ff 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.589+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:584793][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 33 of 80): 46 44 33 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.590+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:590520][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 34 of 80): 00 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.591+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:590838][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 35 of 80): 42 00 69 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.591+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:591342][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 36 of 80): 44 34 36 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.592+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:591623][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 37 of 80): 0e a0 21 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.592+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:591623][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 38 of 80): 62 75 6e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.593+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:592592][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 39 of 80): 42 00 86 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.593+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:592592][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 40 of 80): be 4f 18 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.594+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:593592][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 41 of 80): ae 0e 97 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.594+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:593592][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 42 of 80): 15 26 44 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.595+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:594544][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 43 of 80): 61 21 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.595+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:594544][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 44 of 80): 8b 03 42 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.596+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:595603][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 45 of 80): 03 fe 49 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.596+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:595603][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 46 of 80): 02 0c 6d 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.597+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:596518][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 47 of 80): 69 43 0e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.597+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:596518][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 48 of 80): 8e 0a 6a 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.597+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:597546][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 49 of 80): be ce 53 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.598+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:598492][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 50 of 80): 6c 19 9e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.599+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:598492][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 51 of 80): ac 29 ea 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.599+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:599436][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 52 of 80): 7a ad 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.600+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:599436][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 53 of 80): 3a 31 03 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.600+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:600526][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 54 of 80): 22 1c 82 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.601+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:600526][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 55 of 80): 67 79 fe 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.601+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:601410][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 56 of 80): 01 6a 9e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.602+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:601410][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 57 of 80): 61 62 65 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.603+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:601410][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 58 of 80): 3c 01 fe 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.604+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:601410][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 59 of 80): 01 4a 10 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.611+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:610187][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 60 of 80): 10 5d 5d 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.611+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:610187][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 61 of 80): 70 75 74 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.612+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:610187][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 62 of 80): 03 a5 42 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.613+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:612824][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 63 of 80): 29 1a 24 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.613+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:613555][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 64 of 80): db 01 a1 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.614+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:613925][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 65 of 80): 09 47 66 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.614+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:614588][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 66 of 80): f2 00 0c 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.615+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:614950][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 67 of 80): 45 ab 12 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.615+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:615455][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 68 of 80): 09 2d 57 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.616+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:616065][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 69 of 80): 0c 1d 16 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.616+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:616065][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 70 of 80): 12 e7 ad 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.617+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:617061][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 71 of 80): 5b 1c 7a 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.618+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:617061][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 72 of 80): 13 00 81 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.619+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:617061][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 73 of 80): 46 1d 04 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.619+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:617061][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 74 of 80): af d9 86 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.620+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:617061][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 75 of 80): 0e d9 0d 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.621+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:621114][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 76 of 80): 65 72 2e 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.622+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:621883][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 77 of 80): 20 55 52 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.622+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:621883][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 78 of 80): 00 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.623+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:622877][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 79 of 80): 00 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.623+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (0) [1546854890:622877][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_bm_corrupt_dump, 144: {52837900288, 81920, 4237726079}: (chunk 80 of 80): 00 00 00 
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.623+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1546854890:622877][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_block_read_off, 302: collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt: fatal read error: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1546854890:622877][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_block_read_off, 302: collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt: fatal read error: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.623+0330 E STORAGE  [conn2] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1546854890:622877][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1546854890:622877][3592:140718238684896], file:collection-2-2742384094937205553.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.624+0330 F -        [conn2] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp 408
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.624+0330 F -        [conn2] 

    ***aborting after fassert() failure


    2019-01-07T13:24:50.663+0330 F -        [WTJournalFlusher] Fatal Assertion 28559 at src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp 64
    2019-01-07T13:24:50.664+0330 F -        [WTJournalFlusher] 

    ***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to repair your database?

With mongoshell you can do:

```
db.runCommand( { repairDatabase: 1 } )
```

Make sure you make backup before running this command

Reference
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/

Comment: It worked. some of the corrupted documents are removed but it's fine. Thank you